# Is aiopg supprted for python 3.6 now?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Today I tried to use new version of Python (3.6). I installed `aiopg` by pip (via PyCharm interpreter section tool).
And after I tried to import `aiopg`, exception was happend:

```
from aiopg.sa import create_engine
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\aiopg\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .connection import connect, Connection, TIMEOUT as DEFAULT_TIMEOUT
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\aiopg\connection.py", line 4, in <module>
    import fcntl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'
```

What is `fcntl`? It's linux python native module? In any case it does not work. Any solutions?

Comment: aiopg [doesn't seem to support Windows](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiopg/blob/master/setup.py#L38-L39).

Comment: @dim, on 3.5 is supported...

Comment: That seems odd since `fcntl` is part of the standard library and has been for a while. I don't believe it's available for Windows. Can you import it yourself on 3.5?

Comment: [`fcntl`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/fcntl.html) documentation

Comment: @dim on 3.5 there are no any references of `fcntl` module. And `aiopg.sa` imported successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aiopg==0.11` has a regression but brand new `aiopg==0.12` should work on Windows.